# Unable to find System Image in Emulator in Android Studio with Google APIs

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-api, android-4.4-kitkat

I want to run in Emulator a System Image with Google APIs installed. I downloaded the System Images for API Version 19 (among others). When I go to start a new AVD in Android Studio, for API = 19 - I am not seeing the image with Google APIs. It should be there because I did download it using the SDK Manager (see screen clippings below).

Am I missing something?

[image]

See below screen in AVD Manager showing that the Kitkat does not have an image with Google APIs.

[image]

Comment: Does restarting the android studio help.The google apis should appear rightaway though.

Comment: no unfortunately not. :(

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm facing exactly the same problem.

Comment: Any update on this? Having the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Please try the following solution it's work for me.

If you can not find system image in Android Studio in emulator then go to your Android-SDK you are using in your Android  Studio like C:\Users\MB\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\android-sdk and open AVD Manager.

After open AVD Manager create new AVD and start this newly created AVD.

This AVD is available in your Deployment target and also in your Android Studio AVD manager when you will open AVD Manager next time.

Also, check screenshot for it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately seems there is an issue with the displayed target for the KitKat's system images. It's definitely possible to create an AVD with API 19 and Google APIs as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

To create an AVD with API 19 and Google APIs be sure to select the system image with the Android version **4.4 Google Inc.**

[image]

If you instead select the system image with the Android version **4.4 Android Open Source Project** a standard AVD without Google API will be created.

[image]

Comment: When I choose this Api (19 x86 Google Inc.), and run my app in emulator only what I got on the screen is the message Google Play services are updating. It is there for a while. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Just update all the packages in the SDK manager and restart. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to AVD manager and there in action column click on download.